# mark null rows excluding blank rows pyspark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have the following data stored in the some_people.csv file:

| first_name | age |
| --- | --- |
| :luisa | :23 |
| "" | :45 |
| bill | "" |
| bill1 | :null |

After importing csv it replaces  blank values with null values

| first_name | age |
| --- | --- |
| luisa | 23 |
| null | 45 |
| bill | null |
| bill1 | null |

I need to mark rows which were originally null
I am trying to use this
df = df.withColumn("status", F.when(F.col('category').isNull(),1).otherwise(0))
but this is replacing all the values which were blank in csv

Comment: in your file, what values are supposed to be the NULLs ? you should display some_people.csv data as csv lines (with coma separated values) not as a dataframe.

Comment: @Steven first name values can be empty and spark is replacing all empty values with null 
so i am interested in marking values with new column as 1 which were originally null not the blank ones

Comment: You want to make the difference between `"val1","","val2"` (2 double quotes within two commas = empty) and `"val1",,"val2"` (noting within 2 commas). Is it right ?

Comment: @Steven I just need to mark rows with new column 'status' if value is null for first name (not the blank ones which got replaced by null after import in spark memory from csv)  else 0

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this simple file :

```
a,b
"foo",1
"bar",
"",2
,3
```

basic reading with `spark.read.csv` leads to your current situation :

```py
df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True)

df.show()
+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
| foo|   1|
| bar|null|
|null|   2|
|null|   3|
+----+----+
```

there is a `emptyValue` arg in the [`csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) method :

> sets the string representation of an empty value. If None is set, it uses the default value, empty string

It replaces the empty with some strings. You cannot set it to `""` as it returns NULL, but you can replace it with a space for example.

```py
df = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True, emptyValue=" ")
df.show()

+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
| foo|   1|
| bar|null|
|    |   2|
|null|   3|
+----+----+
```

Then, you can add your status :

```py
df.withColumn("status", df["a"].isNull()).show()

+----+----+------+                                                              
|   a|   b|status|
+----+----+------+
| foo|   1| false|
| bar|null| false|
|toto|   2| false|
|null|   3|  true|
+----+----+------+
```

Comment: yeh you understood it correctly, but issue is that instead of csv we can also have snowflake table as data source so we cannot use empty value check there
`code`

source_df = spark.read \
            .option("sfDatabase", Constant.SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE) \
            .option("sfWarehouse", Constant.SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE) \
            .option("sfSchema", Constant.SCHEMA_NAME) \
            .snowflake("snowflake", Constant.SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE, sql_query)
        return source_df
`code`

Comment: I also found that if I use
df = df.where(a + " is null")
then it is not counting the values which were originally blank but if I use isNULL() it count both the values

Comment: any idea how can I mark rows using this
df = df.where(a + " is null")  with new column status instead of isnull function